# Use Range of Advanced Filter Cells as Criteria for AutoFilter on Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro set up to use an advanced filter on a range of cells on button click, but I would like to then use a range from one column of these filtered values as criteria for an autofilter on another sheet ("study info" and "media," respectively). I'm a total beginner and cannot get the following code to work:

Just added in and edited to code Lowpar provided. It's definitely carrying an array over, but for some reason the only things that are filtered out are the last four entries in the tab with the advanced filter. Here's what I have so far (with code from the first tab included this time)

```
With Sheets("Study Info")
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    Dim y As Integer
    y = (Range("CA3").Value) + 2
    Range("A12:BP150").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("B2:BP" & y), Unique:=False
End With
With Sheets("Media")
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    Dim frow As Integer
    frow = Sheets("Study Info").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim ary() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Set Rng = Sheets("Study Info").Range("B13:B" & frow)
        i = 0
        ReDim ary(0)
        For Each cell In Rng
        ary(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve ary(i)
        Next cell
    Sheets("Media").Range("$A$4").AutoFilter _
    field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=ary, _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to create an array

Comment: `Sheets("Media").Range("$A$4")` that you filter should be more than one cell. Maybe `Sheets("Media").Range("$A$4").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter _` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array called ary with your range, Srow is startrow, Frow is final row.

```
Set rng = Sheets("Sheetname").Range(Tempcol & Srow & ":" & Tempcol & Frow)
        i = 0
        ReDim ary(0)
        For Each cell In rng
        ary(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve ary(i)
        Next cell
        ActiveSheet.Range(Startrow_fil & ":" & Endrow_fil).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm still having some issues, but have updated my code above.

Comment: What's the problem? Sheets("Media").Range("$A$4"), here you need to enter the range you want to filter like Sheets("Media").Range("A1:" & Lastcell). At the moment you are filtering one cell.

Comment: I see what's going on now. When I use MsgBox to see the values of the array, it looks like it's taking values that should have been filtered out for some reason.

Comment: Just had to add the visible cells qualifier to my range. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Show some love so for the solution :P, if you think it genuinely helped, otherwise I'll go back to the drawing board